# Help me to fix a bug in this thread example

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create a thread to simply send the text to client. However, if you copy this code to IDE, you will see that there is a red underline under client.getOutputStream(). I do not know what is wrong here. The IDE says "Unhandled exception type IOException". Could anybody tell me?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServerStudentThread extends Thread {
  Socket client; 

  public ServerStudentThread(Socket x) {  
    client = x;  
  }

  public void run() {
    // create object to send information to client
    PrintWriter out = new  PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);

    out.println("Student name: ");//send text to client;
  }
}
```

For reference, here is the code that calls the thread.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int PORT = 5555;      // Open port 5555

    //open socket to listen
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Socket client = null;

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for client...");

      // open client socket to accept connection
      client = server.accept();

      System.out.println(client.getInetAddress()+" contacted ");
      System.out.println("Creating thread to serve request");

      ServerStudentThread student = new ServerStudentThread(client);
      student.start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what the red underline means have you tried compiling the code to get a compile message?

Comment: @camickr: it said Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException

 at ServerStudentThread.run(ServerStudentThread.java:21)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably that getOutputStream() can throw an exception and you're not catching it, try putting a try / catch (IOException e) around the block of code.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // create object to send information to client    
        PrintWriter out = new  PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        out.println("Student name: ");//send text to client;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException("It all went horribly wrong!", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am just beginner in Java. Yeah, I heard in Java we always need try and catch. Why?

Comment: @Kalla, thats why I provided you with the tutorial link so you can do some reading and not rely on people to post code. That way you understand the concept better.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to add a try/catch block to handle the I/O exception.

Read the section on [Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html) from the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29):

> public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException

[IOException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is a checked exception. You need to use a `try`/`catch` block to handle that possibility.

Answer (score -1):

Kalla,

You need to either put the line in between try/catch block or declare run to throw IOException

Comment: The run method is specified by the `Runnable` interface, if the OP tries to throw a checked exception it will not adhere to the interface. I believe in this case the result will be an overloaded method and a Thread that does nothing when started.